# Finding the highest value in a key-value pair - python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
marks = {'Alex': [9, 8], 'John': [10, 10], 'Raj': [10, 9, 5]}
```

I would like to be able to select the highest mark for each person and store it in a new dictionary in the following way:

```
highest_score = {'Alex': [9], 'John': [10], 'Raj': [10]}
```

My guess:

```
highest_score = {}   
for key, values in marks.items(): 
    #Find highest value
    #store highest value in highest_score
```

How do I find the highest value and store it in the new dictionary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `max` on your `list values`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
highest_score = {key: max(values) for key, values in marks.iteritems()}
```

Note that this will give you the result as:

```
highest_score = {'Alex': 9, 'John': 10, 'Raj': 10}
```

If you actually want each result to still be in a list, use `[max(values)]` instead.

Comment: The OP asked for value to be in a list, change to `key: [max(value)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
highest_score = {k: [max(v)] for k, v in marks.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [50]: highest = {k: [(max(v))] for k,v in marks.iteritems()}

In [51]: highest
Out[51]: {'Alex': [9], 'John': [10], 'Raj': [10]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use max function on list.

```
marks = {'Alex': [9, 8], 'John': [10, 10], 'Raj': [10, 9, 5]} 
highest_score = {}   
    for key, values in marks.items():
        highest_score[key] = max(values)
print highest_score
```

Output:

```
{'Alex': 9, 'John': 10, 'Raj': 10}
```